# How can you describe this kind of graph?

Tags: networking, graph, theory

I know for sure that this is a simple directed graph. But I cannot say that this is a ring graph/network, because node 3 has a degree of 4. But as I imagine this, you cannot go to node 7 from node 3 if the preceding node is node 2, and you cannot go to node 4 from node 3 if the preceding node is node 6. That means the only way to traverse this graph is to start from one node and then go to the adjacent node that has a number greater than the current node (except for node 7 to node 1). What kind of graph is this? Thanks in advance!

http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/5492/graphl.jpg

Comment: Why can't you go to node 7 from node 3 if the preceding node is node 2? Is that a requirement of this graph, or is it you trying to understand the graph?

Comment: no you can't. The graph represents a public utility vehicle route. I do not know if you know this, but in our country, we have these what we call jeepneys. Most of them ply on these kinds of routes. They must follow these routes in order to cover the a certain area. yes, this is a requirement of this graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a simple directed graph. It is also an [Eulerian graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) with exactly one Eulerian circuit. That's probably its most interesting property.

Answer (score 0):

You could redraw the graph as a standard Eulerian Graph without the addition rules by dividing node 3 into two nodes, node 3 and node 6A, where 2-3-4 and 6-6A-7 are the only valid paths through the two nodes. At this point the graph would look like a figure eight. The nodes could then be rearranged in a circle while maintaining the topology.